# Eucalyptus: getting private key from key pair through API / or injecting custom public key to instance

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, eucalyptus

I'm probably having the most simple problem, but I'm still a bit at my wits end. Basically my problems are related to this command:

euca-run-instances -k mykey emi-104915A8

As you know, when starting up instance in Eucalyptus, either through API (as I actually am) or with the command above, the key pair has to be created. If I have understood right, eucalyptus injects the public key of that key pair to the instance. Now there's a method in API (using typica, btw) for creating such a key pair, but I believe when using that it's not possible to get the private key, which I would be needing, since I'd like to do some administrative stuff from external application.

So is it possible to get private keys through eucalyptus api? Or have you managed to find a good solution for injecting externally generated key pairs to instances? I'm between just making my own images and either fooling around with custom-user parameters, or just making some general key pair and putting that straight to image.

I'm just fooling around with Eucalyptus, and trying to get a hand of it, since I think it's best to get to know this cloud concept by trying to implement something on top of it :)

Comment: Well... for this demonstration app fixed this by wrapping ssh stuff and command execution to a function etc... you know the drill. Outcome is the same :)

Answer (score 1):

There is not much that can be done in this matter using Typica. I recommend creating the keypair by ssh-ing into the Cloud Controller and creating the keypair by **euca-create-keypair** command (all this through JAVA). You will get the private key as the output of the command. Save it into a file and carry on.

All the best !!!